# max(x, na.rm = TRUE) returns "NA" anyway

Tags: r, max

I have two vectors val_hps and e:

```
val_hp1 <- -1
val_hp2 <- -1
val_hp3 <- +1
val_hp4 <- -1
val_hps <- c(val_hp1, val_hp2, val_hp3, val_hp4)
e <- c(-.1, -.02, +.03, 0)
```

I would like to select the max value from the set of element of vector e such that:

1. The set contains only the values that have the same position than the negative elements in vector val_hps;
2. The set contains no element with a numeric value of 0.

This is how I proceed:

```
e[e == 0] <- NA
e[max(which(val_hps < 0), na.rm = TRUE)]
```

This should return -.02, but it actually returns NA. 
What do I misunderstand? Thank you!

PS. Replacing the max() function with the min() function works like a charm
+ there is a question elsewhere that looks similar:
"mean( ,na.rm=TRUE) still returns NA", but unfortunately it doesn´t adress my problem..

Comment: Overwriting data with NA seems like a bad idea. You can do `max(e[e != 0 & val_hps < 0])`

Comment: Frank: you nailed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exactly what I expected:

```
max(e[e != 0 & val_hps < 0])
```

@giusti and @Frank: thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Everything works as expected, but you have a mistake in your code. In your last line, you do

```
e[max(which(val_hps < 0), na.rm = TRUE)]
```

`which(val_hps < 0)` returns `1 2 4`, and then the maximum will be `4`. So you will get the value of `e[4]`, which in an unfortunate coincidence (or fortunate) happens to be precisely the element you set to `NA`. This coincidence is why it looked like `min` works and `max` doesn't.

The correct is

```
e[max(which(e < 0), na.rm = TRUE)]
```

This ignores the `NA` in `e` and returns `e[2]` as you wanted.

Comment: giusti: Frank's answer resolved my problem, thank you!